# Prevent Angular summernote from stretching

Tags: angularjs, summernote

In my app, I'm using [angular summernote](https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote) with a bootstrap modal window like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label for="input-m-1">Bio</label>
    <summernote ng-model="model.bio"></summernote>
    <p>The maximum length of 250 characters.</p>
  </div><!-- col -->
</div><!-- form-group -->
```

Everything seems to work fine except for one issue: If I continue typing in the summernote area, without pressing Enter, then it stretches past the boundaries of my modal.

The official documentation says nothing about preventing this. Maybe anyone had this issue or just have any ideas what i can do about it?

Comment: For now i found only a solution in adding ".note-editor{ max-width: /*your number here*/px }", but it doesn't provide responsiveness.